# Pashto Alphabets in Latex

Tags: unicode, languages, xepersian, arabtex

I am writing a paper on Latex (overleaf) that has some Pashto writing. I found this package, [ArabTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX), but it only works for the Arabic and Farsi alphabet, not for Pashto special letters. For example, I want to print the `ښ` letter which has the Unicode of `u+069A`.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Use `babel`, which supports Pashto. (As of 2020, `polyglossia` does not.)  This MWE requires LuaLaTeX from 2020 or later (or `lualatex-dev` might work).

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[english,bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{pashto}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[pashto]{rm}
          {Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont[pashto]{sf}
          {Noto Sans Arabic} % https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-arab
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[pashto]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
For example, I want to print the ښ letter,
which has the Unicode value U+069A. Is there any way to do this?
\end{document}
```

A version that works in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[english,bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import]{pashto}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[pashto]{rm}
          {Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont[pashto]{sf}
          {Noto Sans Arabic} % https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-arab
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[pashto]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\babeltags{pashto=pashto}

\begin{document}
For example, I want to print the \textpashto{ښ} letter,
which has the Unicode value U+069A. Is there any way to do this?
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, it didn't work but after changing the compiler to XeLatex it did work!!! bravoo and thank you so much.

Comment: @QadeerAziz With LuaLaTeX make sure the TeX Live version is 2020 (it works for me).

Comment: @Davislor when I use this, it changes my whole document font. Is there a way to keep to document default font?

Comment: @AzizQadeer Substitute the font you want for `\babelfont{rm}` And any others you prefer. Those are just examples.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I do appreciate that. If you were in Berlin, I would have bought you a coffee. Thank you 

Answer (score 1):

I found a short way to fix this problem and it works perfectly on overleaf. This answer was posted on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/overleaf/status/1322178993479626754).

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{document}
Typesetting \<ښ>
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: My recommendation would be to use LuaLaTeX (from 2020 or later) when you can, then XeTeX as your next option, and 8-bit legacy packages like `arabtex` only when you have to.

Comment: Aha, Thank you so much.